# How I should load file with setkey -f

Tags: linux, fedora

I would like to load a text on Fedora. I use this command:

```
setkey -f "name"
```

but the file cannot be found. I have the file on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have to change into the directory which is your Desktop before. If your desktop is `~/Desktop` then the command you need is:

```
cd ~/Desktop
# the following command shows you the files (and more) in this directory
ls
```

In case you have problems finding your desktop directory: The KDE file manager (Dolphin) has the feature that it can open a shell in the current directory. Maybe your file manager (which should easily find your desktop) can to that, too.